# NullPointerException when using and/or in criteria

Tags: hibernate, grails, criteria

A very simplified example of how I use createCriteria method for getting data in my Grails application:

```
    def c = SomeClassOfMine.createCriteria()
    def projects = c.list(max: limit, offset: start) {
        eq("userId", userId)
        if (owner != null && owner.size() > 0) {
            ilike("ownerName", owner + "%")
        }
        if (someParameter && someParameter.size() > 0) {
            or {
                ne("validated", 1)
                ne("validated2", 1)
            }
        }
        order("name", "asc")
    }
```

On the line having **or {** I get NullPointerException without message. I have tried various combinations and followed closely the examples given in various places only to find that I get the same problem if I try to use **and** too. I know that there are other ways to get the data, but I would very much like to use this approach. I failed to figure out what might be wrong by myself so... What might cause NullPointerException in such code block on **or** / **and**?

I would provide more information if I would know what is relevant in this case.

---

EDIT: Added an if clause (where owner is checked) to code example.

I have investigated more and find out that the problem is in `if (owner != null && owner.size() > 0) {` and to be more specific, the variable name `owner`. When I change the name to anything else the problem is gone. It would be very interesting if someone could explain why this is happening.

Comment: Does it work if you remove the conditional around the `or { }`?

Comment: I would guess that either it's not really a NPE (I love Groovy, but sometimes the stack trace's are not the most useful things) or the NPE is coming from the if statement and not the or{}.  +1 for Rob Hruska's suggestion to try removing the conditional and reporting back...

Comment: I have investigated more and find out that you could not have pointed out the problem as it was in the code I have not shown. I will update my question with new findings.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is "owner" is a reserved word in Groovy. This is described in [Groovy Closures](http://groovy.codehaus.org/Closures). 
You can try placing single quotes around 'owner' so that your line of code would read:

> if ('owner' != null && 'owner'.size() > 0) {

That **may** work. Your best option is to use a new variable name to avoid any confusion.